# How do I force Keynote to sync with iCloud?

Tags: macos, icloud, keynote

When I create new Keynote presentations on my Mac they are not showing up on my iOS devices. I noticed when I open a document from iCloud there is a dotted iCloud symbol in the file viewer.

Is there a way to manually force the sync to occur? Last time I resolved this by disabling my iCloud account and re-enabling it, this is pretty painful though as it takes awhile.

Anyone know why these documents won't sync?

[image]

Comment: I have the same problem but deleting that file and rebooting hasn't worked for me. The sync works the other way - files generated on my iOS devices show fine on the Mac, but if I edit them (or create new ones) the files don't show on iOS. Any further suggestions?

Comment: Check connection and restart Keynotes? I've got this issue today and it has fixed in this way

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok so I got ahold of Apple support and they helped me resolve the issue by deleting the Keynote preferences file located at

`~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.iWork.Keynote.plist`

They instructed me to move it to the Desktop for backup purposes and then reboot the system, after rebooting and opening Keynote again the file was regenerated and the issue was resolved. They then had me trash the old property list file.

Answer (score 2):

In my case that file was not present, so i deleted:

```
~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.iWork09.plist
```

That did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I did not have either of the files mentioned by Chris or Bert. I was able to sync my iCloud files by logging out of my Apple Id account and signing back in.